# connect AAD to existing AKS that has

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac, azure-aks

Working with Azure, we started with AKS last year. On creation of the AKS clusters we use, we checked what needed to be done up front to enable rbac at a later moment and we then thought that setting 'rbac' to 'enabled' was the only thing we needed. This results in the following:

[image]

Now we're trying to implement rbac integration of AKS with AAD, but I read some seemingly conflicting pre-requisites. Some say that in order to integrate AAD and AKS, you need rbac enabled at cluster creation. I believe we have set that correct, looking at the picture above.
But then in the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-integration), it is mentioned that you need to create a cluster and add some AAD-integration keys for the client and server applications.

My question is actually two-fold:

1. when people say you `need rbac enabled in your aks cluster during creation` do they actually mean you `should select the 'rbac:enabled' box AND make sure you create the AAD-related applications up front and also configure these during cluster creation`?
2. Is there a way to setup the AKS-AAD rbac connection on a cluster that has `rbac:enabled` but misses the  aadProfile configuration?

I believe we indeed need to re-create all our clusters, but I want to know for sure by asking here as it's not 100% clear to me from what I've read online (also here at stack exchange) and it's going to be an awful lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all of your requirements, you only need to make sure the RBAC enabled for your AKS cluster and it only can enable in the creation time. Then you can update the credential of the existing AKS AAD profile like this:

Before update:

[image]

CLI update command:

```
az aks update-credentials -g yourResourceGroup -n yourAKSCluster --reset-aad --aad-server-app-id appId --aad-server-app-secret appSecret --aad-client-app-id clientId --aad-tenant-id tenantId
```

After update:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats good news! Thanks for your answer, I’ll try it out this week and will report how it went.

Comment: @LdePudo Do you solve the problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I'm currently fixing some things in the rbac cluster I created anew and when I solve those, I'll apply the above to one of my other environments and will accept the answer when successful. It might take a while, but I'll be sure to remember to accept it.

Comment: @LdePudo What about now? Do you need more help?

Comment: @LdePudo I had wait for serial days and didn't see any updates. So what is the result?

Comment: hi there, sorry to keep this pending for so long. I have used the above suggestions and it works. Many thanks, this is a serious time saver!
I hope many people find this response, as the internet is full with remarks that the above just is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, that is correct
2. no, there is no way of doing that. you need to recreate.